# Uploading Image Path

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to get the image path .. so that i can store it in my database..

can someone help me here?

here is my code..

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
```

message box show alien things .. what i need the msgbox to show is the path of selected image ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((new System.IO.FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName)).DirectoryName +  openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
```

Comment: perfect! btw, how can i add the Filename at the end of the path ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for you.   +openFileDialog1.FileName